# Excel macro to add value to a cell with a formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to set up a macro to add a value, say 10, to an existing cell that has a formula in it. I would like the cell to maintain the formula.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
Sub addvalue 
'Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+A

ActiveCell.Formula = ActiveCell.Formula + 10

End Sub
```

This isn't working for me. It works when the cell is just a number, but not when the cell I am trying to adjust is a formula.

If the cell I'm trying to adjust contains `=A1 + 4` and I run this macro, I'd like it to be `=A1 + 14` after the macro runs.

Comment: Is this exactly as you have it in your file? You're missing the `()` after `Sub addvalue()`...

Comment: You'd have to parse the string returned by `ActiveCell.Formula` and split it based on the `+` or other symbol. If all you need to do is add 10, @ScottCraner's solution seems easy enough.

Answer (score 6):

getting to change the formula itself is problematic.  but you can append the `+10` to the end and get `=A1 + 4 + 10` with:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = ActiveCell.Formula & "+ 10"
```

The issue is that `ActiveCell.Formula` returns a string and you cannot add a number to a string.  You need to concatenate the string and the new part.

---

Edit

To make it so it changes the value instead of concatenating:

```
Sub addvalue()
'Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+A
Dim strsplit() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim dn As Boolean


dn = False

strsplit = Split(Mid(ActiveCell.Formula, 2), "+")
For i = LBound(strsplit) To UBound(strsplit)

    If IsNumeric(strsplit(i)) Then
        strsplit(i) = CDbl(strsplit(i)) + 10
        dn = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

ActiveCell.Formula = "=" & Join(strsplit, "+") & IIf(dn, "", "+ 10")

End Sub
```

This may not work in all cases but for simple formulas it does.

Comment: I'd rather not just append a +10 as it will do this multiple times and it will get messy. I'd like it to actually replace the + 4 with +14 if possible

Comment: @nate the problem comes when you have `+ C8` if we split on the `+` and try to add 10 to that it does not work.  You will need to put a lot of checking in the code to ensure you are appropriately adding the `10` to the correct value.  If you can guarantee that the last value is always `+ somenumber` then it gets easier.    What happens when the value is `=4 + A1` compared to `=A1 + 4` to `=A1 + A2` to `=A1 + 4 + A2` to `=A1 + 4 * A2`.  There are just too many possibilities. The code would need to be massive to ensure all cases are accounted for.

Comment: @Nate see edit.  It should work for most simple formulas.